# Посчитать угол между нормалями без выведения уравнения плоскости

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся со следующей задачей:
Даны координаты вершин треугольников. Надо найти угол между нормалями смежных треугольников (т.е. с 2 одинаковыми координатами вершин из 3)
По классике всё просто: 
записываем определители, считаем их, получаем 2 уравнения для плоскостей.
Коэффициенты подставляем в формулу для косинуса:

```
cos α = |A1·A2 + B1·B2 + C1·C2|/Sqrt((A12 + B12 + C12)(A22 + B22 + C22))
```

Берём арккосинус, получаем угол, радуемся.

Вопрос такой: можно ли как-то проще с точки зрения программы, т.е. без выведения уравнения плоскостей?
Или если нельзя проще, то как считать определитель, который имеет вид:
[{x-2, y+4, z-3},etc]? Это уже не число...

Answer (score 5):

Если у вас есть вершины, у вас есть вектора сторон. Их векторное произведение и даст (ненормированную) нормаль.

Угол между нормалями считается как описано в вопросе (через скалярное произведение).

Comment: так сами нормали есть, они заданы. Мне угол между смежными треугольниками нужен.

Comment: @TheDoctor: Эээ, а что тогда есть угол между _треугольниками_? Разве это не угол между нормалями?

Comment: всё верно вы говорите. Только считается угол между нормалями, как угол, между плоскостями. Эти нормали пихаются в определитель, считается уравнение для плоскости, а затем коэффициенты из этого уравнения и подставляются в выражение для угла. Это всё, что мне гугл сказал в ответ на поиск "угол между нормалями")
Я не хочу париться с выведением этого уравнения, видимо, есть путь проще.

Comment: @TheDoctor: Стойте-стойте. А что есть, по-вашему, нормаль? Это **вектор**. Угол между двумя нормалями — это угол между двумя векторами. А как найти нормаль, написано в ответе.

Comment: видимо, мне пора уже спать. Заданы координаты вершин треугольников, а угол вычисляется между нормалями.
Всё, кажется, я допёр. Спасибо.

Comment: @TheDoctor: Пожалуйста!